# I would like to separate the string that include parenthese

Tags: python, pandas

This is one of list on my csv file.

```
Name                      Combined Score
NDUFAF7 (pp) TRMT10C      0.911
NDUFAF7 (pp) PPARGC1A     0.846
```

It is separate by the (pp), and now i would like to separate into two column.

```
df[['preferredName_A','preferredName_B']] = df['name'].str.split('\s+\(.*$', expand=True)
```

for the code above i will only receive the name infront and the name after (pp) is gone.

I try

```
df[['preferredName_A','preferredName_B']] =df['name'].str.split('(pp)', expand=True)
```

and i will receive the error

Answer (score 1):

your second solution is so close

```py
df[["new_1", "new_2"]] = df["Name"].str.split(r"\s*\(pp\)\s*", expand=True)
```

- escaped the parens
- put some room for spaces around with \s*
- to ensure \ doesn't really escape anything, r"

to get

```py
                    Name  Combined Score    new_1     new_2
0   NDUFAF7 (pp) TRMT10C           0.911  NDUFAF7   TRMT10C
1  NDUFAF7 (pp) PPARGC1A           0.846  NDUFAF7  PPARGC1A
```

Comment: can i know what \s* represent or any document i can watch

Comment: @YikChuanLow `\s` represents a single space (can be normal space, tab etc.) and `*` means "zero or more of what's before". So combined, "zero or more space". I use it because it will also put possible spaces before and after `(pp)` into splitting space and we won't see them. Python's re module has some doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. Another https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is tutorial. In youtube "regex tutorial"s 1st or second episodes should mention \s* structure

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.extract` here:

```py
df[["preferredName_A", "preferredName_B"]] = df["Name"].str.extract(r'(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*) \(pp\) (\S+(?:\s+\S+)*)')
```